# Binding at Design-Time to WPF Labels, Buttons, etc?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

We're developing a WPF & MVVM application that requires multi-language support.  On each control with static text, we're using a converter to do a lookup for the appropriate word for the user's language.

However, this means that each control does not display any text.  This causes some irritation for the UI developers at design-time. Is there any way to display design-time text?

For example:

```
        <TextBlock>
          <TextBlock.Text>
              <Binding Converter="{StaticResource Translator}"
                       Path="Controller"
                       ConverterParameter="Search for" />
          </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
```

How can I make this converter execute at design time to display the translated converter parameter?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest that you use a [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx) for that. Then you markup would look something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{my:Localize Key=MyLabel, Default='The text you want to be displayed by default'}" .../>
```

The default text will also be displayed in Blend.

Second of all I don't see the problems with the converter approach as long as the converter returns a valid default text. In other words converters should be executed in design time as well as in run time.

Comment: Can you clarify?  Markup extensions are a pretty broad topic.  I'm using markup extensions in the code in the above edit.  All bindings are markup extensions.  How can I make the converter execute at design-time?

Comment: Converters should be executed during design time. I'm guessing that the problem in your case is that in desing-time the data context is not set to the right object and therefore the "Controller" path cannot be resolved.

Comment: The controller object is a property of the ViewModel for the View containing the above TextBlock, and is not instantiated until runtime.